# Spark shuffle writes growing out of control

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm using Spark 1.6.1 to process some archives from CommonCrawl. They come as gzipped text files, and I've read that Spark has to load such compressed files into an RDD of a single partition. However, I'm running it on a cluster of ten nodes with 4 CPU's each, so I need to repartition it in order to process the data in parallel. These repartition steps are taking what seems like an unacceptably long time, and when I look on the web UI at the shuffle write times for any repartition step, it grows to over 40 GB, even though one .gz archive is only around 100 MB. Here is the relevant portion of the code I'm running:

```
final WhitelistFilter<String> filter = 
    new WhitelistFilter<String>(WHITELIST_THRESHOLD, termWeights, regex);

//Each URL points to a gzip-compressed text file in the commoncrawl s3 bucket
//With ~40,000 pages per archive
int counter = 0;
for(String s : ccURL) {

    //Obtain WET file from the URL, and filter down to pages of English text
    JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, Text> raw =
        sc.newAPIHadoopFile("sample.wet.gz", 
        org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat.class, 
        LongWritable.class, Text.class, s3Conf)
        .repartition(sc.defaultParallelism() * 3)

    JavaRDD<String> pages = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD( 
        .filter(new WETFilter())
        .map(new WETTransformerWithURL())
        .filter(filter)).keys();

    pages.saveAsTextFile("pages-" + (counter++) + ".txt");
}
```

The various functions called in the filter and map steps are just basic text processing - the most complicated thing is assigning a score based on term frequencies and filtering out anything below a threshold. If I remove the call to repartition(), the entire thing will finish quickly, but without any parallelism. What about the repartitioning could be causing it to be so incredibly slow, and also make the block manager write tens of gigabytes to the disk?